# Programmatically created view not refreshing in ViewPager2 (FragmentStateAdapter)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `ViewPager2` with 4 tabs created with `FragmentStateAdapter`.

3rd tab have content created dynamically: A whole view is created inflating views `layoutInflater.inflate(...)` and the other tabs are just changing view's `layoutParams`.

In both cases those views that have changed programmatically simply doesn't show that changes. Other elements like texts of TextView are displaying changes successfully.

When you simply tap the screen, the view is refreshed and it shows the correct UI.

I tried to do a `performClick()`, `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` in some views, but still doesn't update the view.

Also, when you scroll right to 3rd and 4th tab it also displays the correct UI. The problem is when you directly click on the tab.

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMeYA7Sg-Q8&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Viewpager2 and views disapearing randomly. I also had 4 fragments, and when I jump back 2 fragments it will sometimes not render all views. (Well the space was there for the missing view, it was just not showing it.)

I then realised that those "missing" views where dynamically created (programmably) by me and it was lists inside LinearLayouts. How I had it was "layout.removeAllViews();" and then I recreated the items and then add it back in the list "layout.addView(v);".

So how I solved this was not to remove all the views, but rather just re-use them inside the LinearLayout. Now the views remain on the screen and works perfectly.

I hope this helps! It took me days to figure out what is happening.